# Django Test : __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'failfast'

Tags: django, django-tests

I've a problem with my Django App, this week I added some models and tests but when I'm about to test it with **"python manage.py test"**, I have this error :

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'failfast'
```

I've tried to see if I have some bugs in my models/serializers/tests (syntax error) and even tried to go back to an ancient working commit, but it doesn't solved my issue when testing ...
Also, my server work when I'm using **"python manage.py runserver"**.

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Arh\.virtualenvs\mybacksentinhealth-gHbH4SRy\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Arh\.virtualenvs\mybacksentinhealth-gHbH4SRy\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Arh\.virtualenvs\mybacksentinhealth-gHbH4SRy\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "C:\Users\Arh\.virtualenvs\mybacksentinhealth-gHbH4SRy\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Arh\.virtualenvs\mybacksentinhealth-gHbH4SRy\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Arh\.virtualenvs\mybacksentinhealth-gHbH4SRy\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\test.py", line 53, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "C:\Users\Arh\.virtualenvs\mybacksentinhealth-gHbH4SRy\lib\site-packages\django\test\runner.py", line 633, in run_tests
    result = self.run_suite(suite)
  File "C:\Users\Arh\.virtualenvs\mybacksentinhealth-gHbH4SRy\lib\site-packages\xmlrunner\extra\djangotestrunner.py", line 57, in run_suite
    runner = self.test_runner(**runner_kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'failfast'
```

I don't use the failfast argument in the command line so this error makes no sence for me.
I use Django 2.2.2 !

Here a snippet of what my tests looks like :

```
import pytz
from logging import info
from django.test import TestCase
from django.utils import timezone
from django.test import TransactionTestCase
from apps.myheart.api.api_acquisitions_markers import acquisitions_markers_get
from apps.myheart.models import Implants, Markers, AcquisitionsMarkers, Acquisitions
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from .test_authentication import authenticate

class ImplantsAPIViewTestCase(TransactionTestCase):


    def setUp(self):
            self.implant1 = Implants.objects.create(
                num=1, implantation_date=datetime(2012, 11, 20, 20, 8, 7, 127325, tzinfo=pytz.UTC), implantation_hopital="hopital1"
            )
            self.implant2 = Implants.objects.create(
                num=2, implantation_date=datetime(2014, 11, 18, 20, 8, 7, 127325, tzinfo=pytz.UTC), implantation_hopital="hopital2"
            )
            self.implant3 = Implants.objects.create(
                num=34, implantation_date=datetime(2016, 10, 18, 20, 8, 7, 127325, tzinfo=pytz.UTC), implantation_hopital="hopital1"
            )
            self.token = authenticate()
            self.nb_imp = len(Implants.objects.all())


    def test_implants_get(self):
        info("Test /api/implants/\n")
        response = self.client.get("/api/implants/", HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=self.token)
        info(response.data)
        # We need to check that we have all the files presents in DB
        self.assertEqual(len(response.data), self.nb_imp)
        info("\n")
```

Comment: Have you changed something on the testrunner or anything related to TestCase class, SetUp? I mean, I'm just shoot in the dark here.

Comment: I did not change any code in the packages, and even tried to reinstall all these (I'm using pipenv) to the working version. I'm adding to my question a snippet of what my tests looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with a django project that had worked on python 2 but mysteriously stopped working when I switched to python 3.

For me the solution was to switch from the [xmlrunner](https://github.com/pycontribs/xmlrunner) package to [unittest-xml-reporting](https://github.com/xmlrunner/unittest-xml-reporting)

I.e. try this :-

```
pip3 uninstall xmlrunner
pip3 install unittest-xml-reporting
```

The xmlrunner package is no longer supported, unittest-xml-reporting is the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I just found my bug, seems it was XMLRunner and unittest-xml-reporting that reported me this error. Since I was using them for some times and it worked great I don't know why there are not working anymore but removing them fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Django Testing: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'failfast'
Took me awhile to figure this out with the help of this site. Adding answer for pipenv.

```sh
pipenv uninstall xmlrunner
pipenv install unittest-xml-reporting
```